# I have included values when updating my SQL table, but SQL still treats my values as "None"?? (if I get the error message correctly)

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, cs50

I am still a beginner in CS and I am working on my final project of CS50. I am using the flask framework to build a web application. SQLite is used to handle the database.

The web app aims at letting users read information about different yoga classes (and make bookings, which is a function not yet added). It should also let the administrator, after logging in as admin, easily (1) add new yoga classes and (2) update details of an existing class in the website. The problem I am having now is related to (2). It always shows the error message when I am trying to update the table information with the input in the HTML form.

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Don't know how to render literal SQL value: None

One of the tables in my database is "timetable", each row of which represents one class. The table has columns like id (which is used as primary key), date, price, etc.

After logging in as admin, the admin can enter information in the HTML form of the relevant page to add new row in the timetable i.e. adding new class. I have tested it and it should work fine.

However, when attempting to update details of an existing class, it always shows Error 500 (Internal Server Error). My current approach is like this:

1. Let the admin go to the "manageclass" page, and click "Manage" to show the HTML form for entering new information about the class.

   [image]

   - I have shown the class on 2021-06-04 as an example.
2. The "ID" blank of the form is already filled with a number, which is exactly the "id" of the class in the "timetable" table of the database. It has been disabled so that the admin cannot accidentally change it.
3. For other blanks, the admin just needs to fill in information when attempting to update. For example, when the admin only wants to change the price of the class, just enter the new number in "Price" blank. Then, click "Change!" to submit the form. As the form has attributes `action="/admin/manageclass"` and `method="post"`, it will be diverted to the relevant route in my `application.py`.
4. The function `manageclass()` then handles "ID" (which is pre-filled as mentioned above) and other information added in the form. Part of my code is shown below - assume that I only need to change the price of the class, I only show the part related to class price for you to read more easily.

   ```
    @app.route("/admin/manageclass", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def manageclass():

        if request.method == "GET":        
            # Check whether the user is admin ...
            # If yes, show the table for classes that can be managed ...

        else:        
            # Handle class ID
            class_id = request.form.get("class_id", type=int)        
            ...

            # Handle price (similar code for other items such as location)
            price = request.form.get("price", type=int)
            # When price is provided (similar code for other items such as location)
            if price:
                db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ? WHERE id = ?", price, class_id)        
            ...

            # Return to the manageclass page after successful information update ...
   ```

I reckon the mechanism above should be simple and straightforward, but it eventually messes up because it always shows Error 500. When I take a look at my CS50 IDE terminal, it shows the following error message. The message is long, so I believe that we may focus on the most importance piece of information in the last line:

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Don't know how to render literal SQL value: None`

However, I am quite sure that when running

```
db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ? WHERE id = ?", price, class_id)
```

both `price` and `class_id` are not None?

```
ERROR: Exception on /admin/manageclass [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/ubuntu/project/application.py", line 35, in decorated_function
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/project/application.py", line 338, in manageclass
db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ? WHERE id = ?", price, class_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 21, in decorator
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 178, in execute
_args = ", ".join([str(self._escape(arg)) for arg in args])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
_args = ", ".join([str(self._escape(arg)) for arg in args])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 475, in _escape
return __escape(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 465, in __escape
sqlalchemy.types.NullType().literal_processor(self._engine.dialect)(value))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 3101, in process
raise exc.CompileError(
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Don't know how to render literal SQL value: None
```

I have searched for quite a number of pages on the Internet, but it seems that there are not many friends having the similar problem as mine. Hope I can get some help here, thanks. :(

**--- First update with more information provided ---**

I have just tried to change the following code:

```
db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ? WHERE id = ?", price, class_id)
```

to the following by removing the WHERE clause:

```
db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ?", price)
```

There is no more SQL compilation error as shown before. So I believe that the problem is related to the WHERE clause. Certainly having no WHERE is undesirable because prices of all classes would be changed. But I hope that this small piece of information can be useful for further investigating into the issue.

**--- Second update ---**

I have made some other trials with my code, and when I pass into an integer (instead of variable `class_id`) to my WHERE clause, there is no error:

```
db.execute("UPDATE timetable SET price = ? WHERE id = ?", price, 7)
```

Therefore, I believe that the problem is with the variable class_id, which is in fact `request.form.get("class_id", type=int)`. Some other online resources suggest that `request.form.get` returns a `NoneType`; it can perhaps explain why the error message shows that my value is `None`.

However, even if I put one more parameter `type=int` in `request.form.get` (like what I did above), it still does not work.

I have also tried `request.values.get`, but it still does not work.

I have also tried to cast the value to be an integer by using `int()`, but it does not work as well.

So, problem still not resolved. But hopefully I am nearer to the final solution.

Comment: Thanks James Z for editing my post so that it is more readable!
I have also just added the result of removing the WHERE clause as a trial.

Comment: If `request.get('class_id')` is returning `None` then there is no `class_id` in the form data being POSTed from the browser.  Check the `name` attribute of the `input` tags in the form's HTML.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes I was afraid of that stupid mistake so I have checked the ID input in the HTML form (the one disabled and pre-filled with 7 in the image above), I have included the attribute `name="class_id"`. Therefore, the value "7" should have been POSTed. Thanks though. :D

Comment: Then the next steps are (1) add  `print()` statements that show the values of `class_id` in your code (print after each line that references the variable) (2) open the network tab in your browser's developers and check what is being sent when the form is being POSTed.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Really big thanks - it turns out that the value of `class_id` cannot be POSTed when the input is `disabled`. I hoped that disabling it can avoid the id being accidentally changed (so the information of wrong class will be changed), but I did not know that it would just make my whole application dead. You are not just helping me deal with this problem, but also hinting me some hands-on experience of debugging. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem.  `input` tags have a `readonly` attribute that might do what you want (check the spelling though, it's been a while since I've written any HTML).